# Reading from a CSV File to JSON returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

So I have this function which prints out json object as strings:

```
GetAllArticles: (req, res) => {
        var allArticles = getAllArticles();

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(allArticles));  //cast object to string

        res.end();
}
```

Here is my getAllArticles:

```
function getAllArticles() {
    var result = [];
    result.push(new Article('Gummistiefel', 100, 34.99));
    result.push(new Article('Regenmantel', 10, 124.99));
    result.push(new Article('HTML5 Buch', 25, 4.99));

    //creates a test file
    var json2csv = require('json2csv');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var fields = ["articleName", "quantity","price"];

    var csv2 = json2csv({ data: result, fields: fields });

    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv2, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
    });

    result = [];//clear the array to save new articles

    //load file
    const csvFilePath = 'file.csv'
    const csv = require('csvtojson')
    csv()
        .fromFile(csvFilePath)
        .on('json', (jsonObj) => { 

            result.push(jsonObj);
        })
        .on('done', (error) => {
             console.log('end');
        })



    return result;
}
```

Article:

```
function Article(articleName, quantity, price) {
    this.articleName = articleName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
}
```

And the output on the webpage is: []
So I checked if the loaded jsonObject were in the array and they were, but after I convert them to string the output is just "[]"..

Comment: Verify if allArticles before stringify has object in it.

Comment: why is this tagged asp-net-web-api

Comment: @Alex  sorry my fault. I edited it.. Appereantly in allArticles is empty because length is undefined. I printed the result array in on("done") and it printed 3 Articles but when I return it allArticles is undefined

Comment: @Gururaj Appereantly it doesn't but the array which a return does...

Comment: @KeyNavas - It does not sum up correctly. What happens if you comment out the line where you're resetting the array back to empty. The last return statement in the function should tell you what is being returned.

Comment: @Gururaj If comment out the line result=[] it prints the all values from result but not the loaded ones.... Just the articles which I added at the beginning

Comment: Then something is wrong within these line

const csvFilePath = 'file.csv'
    const csv = require('csvtojson')
    csv()
        .fromFile(csvFilePath)
        .on('json', (jsonObj) => { 
            result.push(jsonObj);
        })
        .on('done', (error) => {
             console.log('end');
        })

Comment: @Gururaj Hmmm I don't know.. The funny part is that i printed out in cvs.done the values of the loaded files and i printed out the length of allArticles and appeantly the thing which was printed was the length of allArticles and than the values, which should be in reversed order

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic cash of asynchronous code

You need to change getAllArticles

```
function getAllArticles() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var result = [];
        result.push(new Article('Gummistiefel', 100, 34.99));
        result.push(new Article('Regenmantel', 10, 124.99));
        result.push(new Article('HTML5 Buch', 25, 4.99));

        //creates a test file
        var json2csv = require('json2csv');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var fields = ["articleName", "quantity","price"];

        var csv2 = json2csv({ data: result, fields: fields });

        fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv2, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('file saved');

            result = [];//clear the array to save new articles

            //load file
            const csvFilePath = 'file.csv'
            const csv = require('csvtojson')
            csv()
                .fromFile(csvFilePath)
                .on('json', (jsonObj) => { 
                    result.push(jsonObj);
                })
                .on('done', (error) => {
                     resolve(result);
                })

        });
    })
}
```

And for your route

```
GetAllArticles: (req, res) => {
    getAllArticles().then((result) => {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));  //cast object to string
        res.end();
    });  
}
```